# Django getting percentage filtering the object

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates, django-queryset

So I have this two models:

```html
class Freguesia(models.Model):
    nome = models.CharField("Freguesia",max_length=255)
```

```html
class Intervencao(models.Model):
    freguesia = models.ForeignKey(Freguesia, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name="Freguesia")
     .........
```

And I want to display in html the top 6 **freguesias** with more **intervecao** and the percentage they have in total

I already can display the freguesias and the number of intervencoes they have , but I don't know how to display the percentage.

My View:

```html
def DashboardView(request):
        freguesias = Freguesia.objects.annotate(num_intervencao=Count('intervencao')).order_by('-num_intervencao')[:6]
        context = {
            'freguesias':freguesias
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using Cast and F

```
from django.db.models Count, F
from django.db.models.functions import Cast
 
freguesias = Freguesia.objects.annotate(
        num_intervencao=Count('intervencao'),
        total=Count('id')
    ).annotate(
        percentage=Cast(F('num_intervencao') * 100.0 / F('total'), FloatField())
    ).order_by('-num_intervencao')[:6]
```

Important to calculate percentage in separate `annotate` not in one where dependant fields are calculated.

Comment: I think you have one more **)** near of the FoatField , and I’m having all the percentage 100%, but the **num_intervencao** are working

Comment: I think the problem was the **total=(Count('id')), because I was receiving the total for each **freguesia**  and not the total for all **freguesias**.
but I already make it work , thanks mate you help me a lot

Comment: Glad to help you!